# ajax call redirects browser erroneously after data is received but using curl shows no redirect in the response from the server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, forms

I have a project on a web-server for class at http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~csoultz/Lab6/mySite.html and in that project there is a form that preforms an ajax GET call to the server. the GET request url looks like `http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~csoultz/Lab6/php/ajaxForm.php?name=me&email=me%40us.com&birthday=12%2F01%2F1998#` .On the server there is a .php file that takes the GET request and returns a response. When the form is submitted the browser receives the data correctly and then after the onload function is called the browser redirects itself to `http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~csoultz/Lab6/mySite.html?name=me&email=me%40us.com&birthday=12%2F01%2F1998#`. However if you run the same request twice in a row then it will work as it is suppose to.

Why is this happening?

when the request is done in curl it returns with status of 200 (ie. no redirect) and the data is correct there as well. Here is the example curl:

```
C:\Windows\System32>curl -i -X GET "http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~csoultz/Lab6/php/ajaxForm.php?name=me&email=me%40us.com&birthday=12%2F01%2F1998#"
```

and here is the response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 06 Oct 2016 15:29:39 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 131
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Thanks for joing our club!

We have filled the following information:

Name: me

Email: me@us.com

Birthday: 12/01/1998

and here is the js code to do the XMLHttpRequest:

```
function askServer() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var birthday = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;

  var dataToSend = "?name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&birthday=" + birthday;
  req.onload = function(){
    if ((this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) && (this.status == 200))
    {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Reply from the server:\n" + this.responseText;
      //console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  req.open("GET", "http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~csoultz/Lab6/php/ajaxForm.php" + dataToSend, true);
  req.send();

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The request has been sent.";
}
```

here is the form:

```
<form action="#" id="workHourCalculator">

  <label for="name">Name*&nbsp;</label>
  <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="inputTextBox" autofocus required><br><br>

  <label for="email">Email*&nbsp;</label>
  <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="inputTextBox" required><br><br>

  <label for="birthday">Birth Date*&nbsp;</label>
  <input name="birthday" type="text" class="inputTextBox" id="datepicker" required><br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit Applet" onclick="askServer()">
</form>
```

and lastly here is the php:

```
<?php
       $name = $_GET['name'];
       $email = $_GET['email'];
       $birthday = $_GET['birthday'];
echo ("Thanks for joing our club!\n<br>We have filled the following information:\n<br>");
echo ("Name: ");
echo ($name);
echo ("\n<br>Email: ");
echo ($email);
echo ("\n<br>Birthday: ");
echo ($birthday);
?>
```

I apologize if there is a firewall up that is blocking the curl call I have not tested outside of my universities network.

Any help is appreciated
Thank You in advance!

Comment: Submit buttons submit. Cancel the form submission.

Comment: I get that, but I think that the professor wanted it to call a function since she specifically wanted the js in another file

Comment: I will add the html and php

Comment: `onclick="askServer(); return false;"`

Comment: the return false in the form did not work it never updated the form

Comment: You can not make an Ajax call and submit a form at the same time... Did you get a 200 back from the server? console.log() and network panel is your friend.

Comment: Yes I did get a 200 back from the server then after the onload call ends the browser redirects to the same page with the parms in the url

Comment: There is no onload.... It redirects because the form submission redirects it... Remove the Ajax call and you will see the form submit and redirect. Canceling the form from submitting stops that from happening.

Comment: The only way I see the 200 is by inserting a break in the onload function and then looking at the network panel...the when I step through it shows me going back to the onclick event handler then to a stack where the only thing there is the response text then if I step one more time the browser redirects to the same page with the parms in the url...the weirdest part is if the same request is made twice in a row it works. I was banging my head on this all night last nigh and I had no where else to turn.

Comment: @epascarello how do I cancel the form? I wonder why the f my professor wants it done this way. There are a million other ways I could do this and this way seems the most idiotic and not practical at all in the real world. I feel as though in the real world I would just use jQuery and call it good to go.

Comment: Changing it to: `onclick="askServer(); return false;"`  and it works, not sure what does not work for you when that happens. I just tested it and the Ajax call is made, text is added under the form, and the form does not submit the page.

Comment: Ok I added the onclick="askServer(); return false;" and it is live on http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~csoultz/Lab6/mySite.html for me on chrome it still does not work. Now it doesn't even make the ajax call when I debug with the network tab

Comment: Because you now have a `}; return false;` inside the call so you never send the request. ANything after that line does not run.

Comment: oops I added that there original and not on the form then forgot to take that off thank you very much. It works now! if you answer it I would be more than happy to mark you as the correct answer and up vote it. @epascarello Would you be willing to explain where the code was going or why the return statement was necessary or point me to a resource that can tell me why?